# que tipo de variable usar para relacionar un radiobutton de VS y el SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, variables, checkbox

Quiero usar desde VS 2012 un radiobutton o un checkbox y no me doy cuenta que tipo de variables tengo que usar en el SQL Server para que me tome bien los datos.
Para salir adelante puse casillas de texto y le permito valores S o N pero es una solución muy mala.
**Usar if checkbox1.Checked y guardar como string S o N también me parece que es una mala practica**.
Debe ser muy simple la solución pero no me estoy dando cuenta.
Probe de definir campos del sql como boolean, bit y algo no funciona bien, **que tipos de variables debería usar en VS y cuales en SQL Server**.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola: En VS los checkBox tienen "tres estados posibles". Indeterminado, activado y desactivado. 
En Sql server una columna tipo bit, al igual que un checkbox, tiene 3 posibles valores. 0 = false, 1 = true y null (ausente de valor)
Si algo no te funciona bien, deberías de poner el código que has implementado para ver donde esta el error.